# Direct conversion from Collection<Long> to LongStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Collection<Long>` (obtained from a `Map<UUID, Long>`'s `values()` method) and I would like to convert it into a `LongStream`.

The simplest way I can think of is:

```
LongStream stream = map.values().stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue);
```

However it strikes me that there should be a simpler way to obtain primitive streams from Collections of boxed equivalents.

I checked `StreamSupport` and could only find `StreamSupport.longStream(Spliterator.OfLong spliterator, boolean parallel)`, but there doesn't appear to be a simple way to obtain an `OfLong` spliterator instance from a `Collection<Long>` either.

I could of course create my own utility function which performs the above `mapToLong` functionality but if there's something built-in I'd rather use that. Apologies also if this has already been asked - I had a search but could find nothing.

Comment: `.mapToLong(Long::longValue)` reflects precisely what you do. You have a collection of `Long` objects and need to invoke `longValue()` on each to get a stream of `long` values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LongStream stream = map.values().stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue);
```

There are no shortcuts (or handy transition methods) in the standard library. I don't see anything wrong or verbose with the approach you mentioned. It's simple and straightforward, why would you need to look for something else?

You could create your own utility class to support it, though I don't think it would be extremely helpful.

```
public final class Streams {
    public static LongStream toLongStream(Stream<Long> stream) {
        return stream.mapToLong(Long::longValue);
    }

    public static Stream<Long> toStreamLong(LongStream stream) {
        return stream.boxed();
    }

    private Streams() {}
}
```

Comment: I would be confused about the `toLongStream` method not returning a `LongStream`. I would instead name them `LongStream toLongStream(Stream<Long>)` and `Stream<Long> toStreamOfLongs(LongStream)` or something.

Comment: @MCEmperor `toLongStream` does return a `LongStream`

Comment: @MCEmperor `toStreamOfLongs` is kinda verbose, though it's more accurate

Comment: `toStreamOfLongs` would not make clear whether it’s a `LongStream` or `Stream<Long>`, as both are streams of longs. Anyway, the utility method to call `boxed()` is obsolete and the most natural name of the other would be `unboxed`…

Comment: @Holger I am hiding how it's being done... Internally, it could be `.mapToObj(Long::valueOf)` (which is a worse alternative, of course)

Comment: `boxed()` is already hiding how it’s being done. Of course, you can encapsulate *any* piece of code in a method. And then encapsulate the invocation of the method in another method. And again…

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I'm sorry, I was convinced that it was the other way around, but apparently I didn't read too well. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Just let the compiler decide how to *unbox* `Long` instead of dictating him to call `Long.longValue()`.

Straightforward:

```
Map<UUID, Long> map ...
LongStream stream = map.values().stream().mapToLong(l -> l);
```

or give this lambda a name and get a more readable version:

```
LongStream stream = map.values().stream().mapToLong(unbox())

ToLongFunction<Long> unbox() {
    return l -> l;
}
```

Maybe there is a `unboxed()` method as a counterpart to [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#boxed--) someday.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best that it's not super easy, since it's a performance trap.

Unboxing a stream is a little dangerous, because it's common for downstream operations to require boxed values, and they're usually boxed automatically.

Working with boxed values you already have is not really expensive, but re-boxing unboxed values is, so facilitating stream unboxing produces more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mapToLong` isn't *that* complex, so a simpler way wouldn't make much of a difference.

The problem is that even if you know that you have a `Collection<Long>`, it's still a `Collection` of objects. Now if there were a `LongCollection` class, there might be a `toLongStream()` method, but that would then have other issues.